# Generate uml diagram from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, uml, class-diagram

I want to generate an UML diagram from  Eclipse (code to uml diagram) and when I searched for that I found a tool called OrientedAid in github that you add to your Eclipse program. I installed it but when I'm using it it won't work .. when I press the finish button it doesn't work .. like it's showing in the pic :

[image]

What is the issue here?

Comment: You may want to try this https://plantuml.com/eclipse